# recharts LabelList not working when isAnimationActive set to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend, recharts

I'd like to add value label on each bar but  is not working even though it's simple Bar chart.

I tried isAnimationActive set to false but it came this error: [Error handled by React Router default ErrorBoundary: Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead.]

And below is codes I wrote:

```
export const StackedChart = (props) => {
    const data = [
        {
            name: 'a',
            ref: 0,
            cur: 4500,
        },
        {
            name: 'b',
            ref: 1000,
            cur: 3500,
        },
        {
            name: 'c',
            ref: 1500,
            cur: 2000,
        },
      ];

    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer width="99%" height="99%">
            <BarChart
                width={500}
                height={324}
                data={data}
                margin={{
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    left: 20,
                    bottom: 0,
                }}
            >
                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" vertical={false} />
                <YAxis axisLine={{strokeWidth: 0.2}}/>
                <Tooltip />
                <Bar dataKey="cur" stackId="a" fill={colorSet.prim700} isAnimationActive={false} >
                    <LabelList dataKey="cur" />
                </Bar>
                <Bar dataKey="ref" stackId="a" fill={colorSet.prim50} />
            </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    )
}
```